# How to switch types in Lean theorem prover when constants are involved?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

For a newcomer working through the LEAN documentation, it is sometimes quite frustrating to see that some simple problems turn into real bottlenecks when more difficult ones have apparently been solved. Here is what was supposed to be a simple self-produced exercise that turned into a few hours of frustration (there's no other way to LEARN, of course):

```
theorem prByCont : ∀ P : Prop, ( P → false ) → ¬ P :=
    λ (P : Prop) (prf : P → false), prf
#check prByCont

example ( a b : ℕ ) (p: a = 2) (q: b=3) : ¬ (a ≥ b) :=
begin
    apply prByCont,
    assume h : a ≥ b,
    have order : 2 < 3 := dec_trivial,
    contradiction
end
```

The problem seems to be that `order` has type `2<3` but what is needed is `a<b`, and although it looks to me that it should be clear that `a=2` and `b=3`, LEAN doesn't think so. Please help me see what I'm missing here!

Comment: You can `rw [<- p, <- q] at order` and then `order` will have exactly the right type.

Comment: The `contradiction` tactic needs a more obvious contradiction than this. So you need `p` and `¬ p` - it doesn't automatcially apply the fact that `a < b ↔ ¬ b ≤ a`

Comment: inserting the line `rw [← p, ← q, lt_iff_not_ge] at order,` before `contradiction` fixes the proof.

Comment: Incidentally the easiest proof of this is `begin
  rw [p, q], 
  exact dec_trivial
end`

Comment: These all work. But if `b=3` is changed to `b=a+1` things fail again. Why are these not recognized as being the same, given the hypothesis for `a`?

Comment: `dec_trivial` only works when there are no free variables in the statement. So if there is a variable `a` in the statement then `dec_trivial` will not work. I think the proof `rw [q, p], exact dec_trivial` will work, since after these rewrites there are no variables in the goal. 

The `exact` tactic does not use equalities in the context to match the proof to the goal. So you do have to use `rw` first.

Comment: @Vox You are reasoning on a higher level (which is completely fine). The lower level tactics that you are using are meant to do only very simple stupid predictable things. If you have Lean's mathlib available, you could try `import tactic.linarith` at the top of your file. Then `begin linarith end` will prove your lemma. `linarith` is a tactic designed for proving inequalities like yours. It is smart, and uses facts like `b = a+1` from the context.

Comment: @jmc Right, I had already done it with `linarith` before getting into this. My problem is not just doing it to go past it, but rather to understand all the details so I can use LEAN with confidence in the future. And the available documentation seems a little thin in this regard. Any suggestions on how to improve faster?

Comment: One thing you can do is turn the `example` into `lemma foobar`, prove it using `linarith` and inspect the proof that `linarith` finds using `#print foobar`.